# How to get all rows from calender table using a resultset as input

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need to find all dates between 2 dates from a resultset.
My database has a calendar table that holds one row for each date from a few years ago until far enough into the future.

Now I have this query

```
select convert(date, r.LaadDatum), 
       convert(date, r.LosDatum)
from   tblPlanning p
  inner join tblRit r on p.RitID = r.RitID 
where  r.ChauffeurID = 201
and    (convert(date, r.LaadDatum) >= '20180812' and convert(date, r.LaadDatum) <= '20180921')
and    datediff(day, r.LaadDatum, r.LosDatum) > 1
```

and it returns this result set

```
COLUMN1     COLUMN2 
-------     ------- 
2018-08-14  2018-08-16  
2018-08-20  2018-08-22  
2018-09-01  2018-09-03  
2018-09-08  2018-09-10  
2018-09-14  2018-09-17
```

Using this resultset as input, I need the following result :

```
2018-08-15  
2018-08-21  
2018-09-02  
2018-09-09  
2018-09-15  
2018-09-16
```

In other words, all rows from the calendar table that are between the dates from the query above. The calendar table is called tblCalendar.
How can this be done ?
Probably very simple but for some reason i just dont see it

Comment: Do an OUTER JOIN!

Comment: @jarlh A left outer join did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cte recursive with `DATEADD` function.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DATEADD (DAY,1,COLUMN1) COLUMN1,COLUMN2
    FROM T
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD (DAY,1,COLUMN1) ,COLUMN2
    FROM CTE
    WHERE  DATEADD (DAY,1,COLUMN1)< COLUMN2
)
SELECT COLUMN1 
FROM CTE
ORDER BY COLUMN1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e900a36182659d05b029d43f859f69d3)

Comment: This also works, but I think I will stick with the outer join as suggested by jarlh

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this.

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE (Column1 DATE, Column2 DATE);

INSERT INTO @myTable (Column1, Column2)
VALUES ('2018-08-14', '2018-08-16')
,      ('2018-08-20', '2018-08-22')
,      ('2018-09-01', '2018-09-03')
,      ('2018-09-08', '2018-09-10')
,      ('2018-09-14', '2018-09-17');

WITH cte AS
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RN
       FROM master..spt_values)
SELECT          DATEADD(DAY,rn,Column1) DayToShow
  FROM          @myTable
 CROSS APPLY    cte
 WHERE DATEADD(DAY,rn,Column1) < column2
```

You should find it quicker than the iterative cte method, however it is limited to date ranges of about 2,500 days. You can crossaply inside the cte to give more rows if you want.

Comment: 2500 is more than enough in my case. The maximum days between will be about 15. So thanks for the alternative

Answer (score 0):

i would use cursor here. it's like for each.
please try this code. the output is @TempTable which contains all between dates

```
Declare @TempTable table (BetweenDate datetime)
Declare @FromDate datetime, 
        @ToDate datetime,
        @date datetime

Declare DatesCursor Cursor For
        Select FromDate, ToDate From (
                     select convert(date, r.LaadDatum) FromDate, 
                            convert(date, r.LosDatum) ToDate 
                     from   tblPlanning p
                        inner join tblRit r on p.RitID = r.RitID 
                     where  r.ChauffeurID = 201
                         and    (convert(date, r.LaadDatum) >= '20180812' 
                         and convert(date, r.LaadDatum) <= '20180921')
                         and    datediff(day, r.LaadDatum, r.LosDatum) > 1) t


    Open DatesCursor
    Fetch Next From DatesCursor Into @FromDate,  @ToDate

    While @@Fetch_Status = 0
    Begin
        If (@FromDate is not null and @ToDate is not null )
            Begin
                SET @date = DATEADD(day, 1, @FromDate) 
                WHILE (@date < @ToDate)
                BEGIN
                    insert @TempTable Values(@date)
                    SET @date = DATEADD(day, 1, @date) 
                END
        END
        Fetch Next From DatesCursor Into @FromDate,  @ToDate
    End

    Close DatesCursor

    select * from @TempTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but allthough this can work, a cursor is to slow for my taste